# The stronger the gravity, the faster an object will fall?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, planets

On a planet with gravitation ten times stronger than that of Earth's, will an object fall faster? Let's suppose that there are two planets; Roddo and Earth, respectively. Roddo has ten times the surface gravity than Earth. If I drop two apples about 8000 meters away from the surface on both Roddo and Earth at the same time, will the apples hit the surface at the same time?

Comment: What do you think will happen here?

Answer (score 2):

> On a planet with gravitation ten times stronger than that of Earth's,
>   will an object fall faster?

Yes.

It will have ten times greater acceleration. If it starts out at the same height as on earth it will be going faster when it hits the ground and it will hit the ground in less time.

> If I drop two apples about 8000 meters away from the surface on both
>   Roddo and Earth at the same time, will the apples hit the surface at
>   the same time?

No.

This part of your post is starting to feel like a homework question, so I won't work through it in detail. You should be able to apply basic kinematic equations to this problem.